# website touch is not working on iPad or iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, touch

I am working on a project for different device. Site is responsive and mobile device enable.
locally checking with Firefox touch device working perfectly. but when i have uploaded it its not working. I have tried all the available resources of stack overflow but nothing worked.
my site URL is [Stillmans](http://www.stillmans.pk)
                $(pull).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

```
        $(menu).click(function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();  
            menu.slideToggle();  
        });
```

please help me, i am kind of in stress.

Answer (score 0):

Your website appears to have some javascript errors on the window.resize jquery function (line 148) that I noticed after changing my browser size.  It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: menu is not defined".  I believe that this error is due to the fact that menu isn't declared till after, the window.resize function on line 146.  Please move this function to somewhere after the menu variable is being declared.

Comment: please check i've move the mention script before. if i am not doing it wrong

Comment: i've commented the particular script

Comment: it worked. i've replace the code and it worked like a charm. all i need to check it on smart devices. Thank you chris, your the man!

Comment: yes it did... one more issue raise. clicking on anchor take whole website to top:0, i have tried e.preventDefault(); but it stop ipad trigger :(